# Why `muted` attribute on video tag is ignored in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Well, as counter-intuitive as it sounds, `muted` tag is somehow ignored; check out the snippet below,
first one is rendered with react, the second one regular html; inspect them with your dev tools, and you see the react on **doesn't** have `muted` attribute; I already tried `muted={true}`, `muted="true"` but non is working.

```js
function VideoPreview() {
  return (
    <div className="videopreview-container">
      React tag:
      <video
        className="videopreview-container_video"
        width="320"
        height="240"
        controls
        autoPlay
        muted
      >
        <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpsthecoder/h/gh-pages/OSRO-animation.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<VideoPreview />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>


<hr/>
Regular html:
<video
  width="320"
  height="240"
  controls
  autoplay
  muted
>
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpsthecoder/h/gh-pages/OSRO-animation.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: well it seems to mute video on my end...

Comment: @AneesIjaz no the video doesn't have sound; its a preview link

Comment: have you tried with a video that have sound. may be instead of adding an attribute react changes the player's property directly to muted.

Comment: The property is set through js not through the html attribute. If you add a video with audio, you will see that it is correctly muted.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli the thing is `autoPlay` policy require the video to be muted, and without that attribute how is it going to understand if the video is muted or not

Comment: @AneesIjaz I'd added a video with sound, and yes its muted, but why its still not showing like other attributes :(?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10389) which has existed since 2016.
The video will be muted correctly, but the property will not be set in the DOM.
You can find multiple workarounds in the GitHub issue, although there might be pros and cons with any of them.

Comment: I recommend doing as idoliki suggests and use `useRef`: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10389#issuecomment-1601018277

`const isMuted = useRef(false);  return <video muted={isMuted.current} ... />`

OR

use `useMemo`:

`const volumeMuted = useMemo(() => { return videoOnly || !volumeEnabled }, [isMuted]); return <video muted={volumeMuted} ... />`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @FluidSense it is an open bug since forever.

I could achieve it like this:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Video({ src, isMuted }) {
    const refVideo = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!refVideo.current) {
            return;
        }

        if (isMuted) {
            //open bug since 2017 that you cannot set muted in video element https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10389
            refVideo.current.defaultMuted = true;
            refVideo.current.muted = true;
        }

        refVideo.current.srcObject = src;
    }, [src]);

    return (
            <video
                ref={refVideo}
                autoPlay
                playsInline //FIX iOS black screen
            />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I dealt with it using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class VideoComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    videoStr: "",
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { src } = this.props;
    const videoStr = `
        <video autoplay loop muted>
            <source src=${src} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    `;
    this.setState({ videoStr });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.className}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.videoStr }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`muted` works if you type it as `muted="true"`. Using the string true sends the attribute to the DOM now

Comment: I just check with `react@18.1.0` & `muted="true"` and it didn't show up

Comment: You're right. I was using react in a Next.js app and for some reason this works there with react@18.1.0 (demo here: https://houseoftheseus.com/). But spinning up a code sandbox with this didn't work at all. I'm not sure why. https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-shamir-5sohzh?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

from my own project. (WORK)

const Header = () => {
const [isMuted, setIsMuted] = useState(false);

return (

```
<div className="header">
  <video src={headerBg} autoPlay loop muted={isMuted? true : false} />
  <div className="container" >   
      <div className="btn-mute" onClick={() => setIsMuted(!isMuted)}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would also note that some browsers like Chrome might have a limit for the file size a video can be. I was running my own videos on my website and when I inspected the page and looked under `Sources` I did not find the video I had used and been looking for. This forced me to investigate further. I realized the video that I was running was about 10.4mb. It was large relative to the usual payload of a website so I lowered the size to around 5mb and the video appeared on my site.

Some other information about my steps to finding a solutions was that I was using my localhost to run my React app. I also ran my React app on Safari which surprisingly displayed my video even when the size was 10.4mb. I'm guessing that browsers have different criteria for video sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, so I made a custom HTML element that adds the muted video. Here is the custom muted video:

```
class MutedVideo extends HTMLVideoElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.muted = true;
    // I also noticed that you used autoplay, so I added it too.
    this.autoplay = true;
  }
}

customElements.define("x-muted", MutedVideo, { extends: "video" });
```

And here the video preview.

```
// Notice how I removed the muted and autoPlay props and added the 'is' prop

function VideoPreview() {
  return (
    <video
      is="x-muted"
      width="320"
      height="240"
      controls
      src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpsthecoder/h/gh-pages/OSRO-animation.mp4"
    >
      Sorry, your browser does not support the HTML video tag
    </video>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muted-react-video-9wiz4y) is a working demo